# php symbolic link for images

Tags: php, iphone, image, symbolic-references

I have images which change often as part of a website and iphone app. Imagine that it is a user image and they can change their picture often (although it is for much more than that).  I need to have the image change name when the content changes so that an iphone client with caching mechanisms knows to update what it has as a new image.  However when I send emails with these image paths, after they change the old links are broken.  To try to get around this I would make a symbolic link which would be fixed and simply point at the most recent version of the image.  In this way the emails can use the symbolic link and will never break, and the iphone client can still get the most up to date version.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this in php -- changing the link and/or making it  -- and if this would even behave the way I want for images?  Is there a better way I could solve this problem?

Comment: My 2 cents: Either simply do not delete the old image (for a while), or simply overwrite the same image and use HTTP caching better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even try to google "PHP Create Symbolic Link"? Here is the first result:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php

Comment: Yes, and thank you but I was really mostly wondering about whether this is a good way to go about solving the problem

Comment: And also if the symbolic link would act as an image and download correctly

Comment: That isn't really clear by your question. Anyways, yes a link will act like an image (or whatever it is a link of) and download correctly.